# Texture paint is grainy in some areas of the mesh and solid in others. I am also not able to select regions for paint masking

Tags: uv, texture-painting, masking

Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem. I have never modeled a day in my life but recently I am trying to learn more about Blender as my company produces incredible models and I personally want to learn more about the process. I have created my first model (Gabe) through a guide available on SkillShare. The guy is using the same version of the program I am, but appears to be getting different results.

For instance, some of my paint is turning up "grainy" in some areas and smooth in others such as the feet.[image]

Additionally, there are strange lines on the feet that I cannot paint over.[image]

Lastly, I am unable to select parts of the model/mesh with the masking tool function such as the upper and lower parts of the beak. This is probably something I am not understanding/messing up on as the guy in the tutorials kinda just did it without showing specifically how to do it, just vague steps you can only make out if you are going at 0.25x.[image]

Thank you all so much for the help!

Comment: Check to see if you have a texture in the Brush texture or Mask Texture slots, delete them - because it looks like procedural noise patterns. The Face Select Masking needs to be toggled on and then you can use the Circle selection button to select faces to paint to.

Comment: Hi Craig! Sorry for the late reply, didn't get a notification that my question had been answered! So in both the brush texture and texture mask, I have them set to by default, tiled. When it comes to the circle selection it is only letting me select what I "draw on" rather than tabbing to the piece I want to edit such as the beak. Is this because I've merged the pieces into one mesh?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this is the one I stumbled upon when it happened to me, and I found a solution, so I thought I'd share it in case someone else has this problem and ends up here too.

I [posted it on my Ko-Fi Page](https://ko-fi.com/post/Grainy-texture-map-stroke-when-painting-on-mesh-D1D8L17X9) with images, but what happened to me was I had mirrored the mesh at one point and must not have clipped and bisected it, which caused noise when I painted on the mesh, but not when I painted on the texture map.

If the OP finds this let us know if that's a possibility :) Cuz my issue went away when I made a new mesh.